# Create a directory at SharePoint without the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly from C#

Tags: development, directory

Is it possible to create a directory in SharePoint from c# code without using the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly? I would like to create some folders and upload after that few files to them. I think the upload is not the problem. The program should run on a Non-SharePoint machine, so I cannot use the assembly. Any ideas? Greetz.

**Edit**
Or is it possible to add the metadata to the folder, if I create them about the WebDAV of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are a variety of ways. I would recommend using SharePoint's web services and calling the [UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method. You'd build XML like:

```
<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
   <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
   <Field Name="FSObjType">1</Field>
   <Field Name="BaseName">Name</Field>
</Method>
```

Then, using the C# example at the bottom you can call the webservice.

There are [other ways to create folders by using webdav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630824/sharepoint-how-to-create-a-folder-in-a-document-library-please-using-web-servic) which may be worth investigating.

Comment: Well, I will have a look tomorrow and gave you feedback, how it works.

Comment: A benefit from using web services is that you can add additional `Field` nodes for your folder's metadata.

Comment: Does the UpdateListItems method also work for libraries in SharePoint? It sounds like it’s for lists and pages with asmx extension. Greetz?

Comment: In addition, does the program run on a pc without SharePoint installation, if I use the SharePoint Services?

Comment: 1) Yes it works for libraries. 2) The asmx extension means it is a webservice. 3) Yes, no SharePoint installation needed. I would recommend getting familiar here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc537498(v=office.12).aspx#MOSSIntroToNet_ComponentsWebServices

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, but not always possible, is to use the webdav features of SP.

You can navigate with windows explorer using :

```
\\your.web.application\DavWWWRoot\sites\yoursite\yourlib
```

Comment: Yea, that’s actually the way which I use at the moment… But sadly the Metadata are missing at the directories. Could I add them afterwards?

Comment: You can use an Http PUT query to drop files, then use the webservices to manipulate the data (also possible using webdav, but never tried)